# Add files to each branch in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have 55 branches in various locations. For example $/Repo/Trunk, $/Repo/Branches/branchNames, $/Repo/Features/branchNames, etc. I want to add some files to every branch. I scripted a copy and paste to put the files in the subfolder under each branch where I'd like to add them.

I then navigated to C:\TFS\Repo (my workspace for Repo) and searched for NewFile. Windows explorer brought up a list showing the 500 new files I'd just added across the 50 branch folders. I highlighted all of them, right-clicked, chose Team Foundation Server -> Add.

Here's my problem: it only added ten of them. I don't want to go back and redo that process, making sure to deselect everything I've already added (because if it's selected, the 'Add' option is disabled), and repeat this process 50 times. I also tried a script that will recursively search for files starting with NewFile and add them but it only added 300 of them (not sure why).

Am I missing something or is there no easy way for me to add all these files at once?

Comment: I  can't imagine a senario where having 50 active branches is a good idea!

Comment: @MrHinsh I agree :) However, they aren't all active and it's not my decision anyway.

Comment: Who's decision is it and go speak to them... Or give them my email 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the File Explorer extension.  Add the files via the Source Control Explorer in TFS.  Right click on the root folder for the branches and choose `Add Items to Folder`.  The dialog will show all files that could be added (including subfolders) and you can include/exclude as necessary.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This method will break the branching model for those files. After checkin there will be no branch relationship between the files and they  will never merge.

You need to add the Files to one of the branches  and merge them through the branch structure.

Ideally you would add them to your MAIN/TRUNK/MASTER and then merge that out to all of your DEV and FEATURE branches. You are  unlikely to want to do this for RELEASE but I can imagine senarios where this would be necessary.